# Angular Directive that may or may not be a child of another angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

Recently I decided to learn Angular. It's a great framework and I've had quite a bit of fun with it, but I've gotten to the real meat-and-potatoes portion of it: Directives. I think they're probably the best thing to happen to HTML since CSS transitions. I built a website that utilized a strange altered-tab format for a few places (the contents of the page are loaded in these tabs, and a variation was used for the FAQ page)

In my own messing around, I came across the `<menu>` tag and remembered my disappointment with it. I want to build a directive that alters the menu tag into its own type of navigation menu for a website, with drop downs for items that have sub-menus as child elements. Example:

```
<menu>
  <menu-item menu-link="/">Home</menu-item>
  <menu-item menu-link="/about">About</menu-item>
  <menu-item menu-link="/something/" menu-title="Something">
    <menu>
       <menu-item menu-link="/something/sub-item1">Sub Item 1</menu-item>
    <menu>
  </menu-item>
</menu>
```

I want for the menu inside the menu-item tag to be hidden, until the menu-item for 'something' is moused over. And I want for this to be applicable to for any combination of `<menu> -> <menu-item> -> <menu> -> ...` as one may need for an actual navigation menu.

Here is the in-progress information from my javascript, keep in mind I was fiddling around to see if I could get something working.

```
app.directive('menu',function(){
    
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            require:'?^menuItem',
            scope:{
                id:'@',
                text:'@'
            },
            link:function(scope,element,attr,parentItemScope){
                console.log("Parent Item Present?", !angular.equals(parentItemScope,undefined));
                if(!angular.equals(parentItemScope,undefined)){
                    parentItemScope.helloSubMenu(scope.id);
                    parentItemScope.updateSubmenu();
                }
            },
            transclude:true,
            template:'<div ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    
    });
    
    app.directive('menuItem',function(){
        
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{
                menuLink:'@',
                menuTitle:'@'
            },
            controller:function($scope,$attrs){
            
                if(angular.equals($attrs.menuTitle,undefined)){
                    //How do you get the HTML value for ones that don't have submenus???
                }
            
                this.helloSubMenu = function(menuId){
                    console.log("Called from a menu within a menu-item tag! Menu ID is :", menuId);
                }
                
                this.updateSubmenu = function(){
                    $scope.hasSubmenu = true;
                    $scope.hideSubmenu=true;
                };
                
                $scope.toggleSubmenu = function(){
                    if($scope.hasSubmenu == true) $scope.hideSubmenu = !$scope.hideSubmenu;
                };
                
                $scope.hasSubmenu = false;
                $scope.hideSubmenu=true;
                
                
            },
            transclude:true,
            template:'<a ng-href="{{menuLink}}" ng-mouseover="toggleSubmenu()" ng-mouseout="toggleSubmenu()" class="btn btn-default">{{menuTitle}}</a><span ng-transclude ng-hide="hideSubmenu"></span>'
        };
        
    });
```

My main question for right now is this: For the elements that are 0-level (aka, no child `<menu>` tags), how do I gather the HTML value passed and set it to the menu-title attribute that is passed for items with child `<menu>` tags?

Any help is appreciated. I know the answer has something to do with the transclude function, I'm just not sure how to use it. I've passed $transclude to the menu-item controller before, but setting the `$scope.menuTitle` property within the passed function didn't change anything - the links all showed up empty.

### Note## I am using bootstrap css.

Comment: Could your put up a jsfiddle or a plnkr with the code?

Comment: I can never get JS Fiddles with angular to work, but let me try. Edit: Literally cannot get it to even pretend to work. Doesn't even find the app module I made, just throws an error.

Comment: Take this working plnkr from the angularjs docs and replace with your own code: http://plnkr.co/edit/R12nrS?p=info

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/96FNFTqZzmge0jqQsRjc?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9su69j8vNygcyzPpHOZj?p=preview I've got this going. Took some wizardry and a page 2 of the google searches (I know). Now my problem is that for the ones that don't have a submenu, how do I get rid of the element, as you can see in my example

Comment: Nice one, I got hung up on trying to make it look nice like a proper bootstrap menu and ran out of time.

Comment: I'm still stuck on getting rid of the transcluded element if there's no reason to have it there, but so far I've got something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When removing the

```
$scope.hideSubmenu=true;
```

statement when the directive controller is created it seems to work.

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sg560740/3/